# How to determine what potential to use in an overlap integral?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I am studying the Tight Binding Method (LCAO) to calculate bind structure. I understand the general idea, but I am having trouble calculating the overlap integral. In particular, I am not sure on what criteria to use to decide on what potential to use.

Is that always an approximation, and thus the decision is taken based on the compromise between accuracy and difficulty of computation? Is it correct to expect that if I combine higher energy orbitals I should account for the influence of more atoms in the crystal?

For example, if I want to calculate the overlap integral of s-orbital, using hidrogenic potentials, for a simple cubic lattice, is it reasonable to take as the potential the Coulomb attraction of the 6 nearest neighbors?

Thank you.